# Javascript - Map an array of strings to an array of objects with multiple object properties

Tags: javascript

So I have something like this:

```
var myArray = ["cherry", "Michigan", "potato", "Idaho", "apple", "NewYork", "Burrito", "California"]
```

I need to convert into:

```
[ 
{id: 1, foods: "cherry", location: "Michigan"},
{id: 2, foods: "potato", location: "Idaho"},
{id: 3, foods: "apple", location: "NewYork"},
{id: 4, foods: "burrito", location: "California"}
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop you array in the following way:

```js
const myArray = ["cherry", "Michigan", "potato", "Idaho", "apple", "NewYork", "Burrito", "California"]
let result = []
for(let i=0; i< myArray.length -1; i+=2) {
  let id = result.length + 1
  let foods = myArray[i]
  let location = myArray[i+1]
  result = [...result, {id, foods, location} ]
}

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

If your array data structure always be like that, you can do this:

```js
var myArray = ["cherry", "Michigan", "potato", "Idaho", "apple", "NewYork", "Burrito", "California"]
let outputArr = []
let id = 1;
for(let i = 0; i < myArray.length -1; i +=2) {
 outputArr.push({
     id: id,
        foods: myArray[i],
        location: myArray[i+1]
    })
    id++;
}

console.log(outputArr)
```